# Lucene query result : get the words in the returned documents that were found by the query

Tags: lucene, full-text-search

In order to present highlighted match-words in the documents that were returned by Lucene queries, Lucene search result may contain the words that were used to return the doc as matching my request.

For example :

- Lucene query : "dog cat"
- Result : ["**dogs** are nice","**dog** and **cats** are friends"]

How to achieve this with Lucene? Manually I can't handle cat**s** or dog**s** or any difference between requested words and returned words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Lucene's [`Highlighter`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_0/highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/Highlighter.html).  Something like this:

```java
//By default, this formatter will wrap highlights with <b>, but that is configurable.
Formatter formatter = new SimpleHTMLFormatter(); 
QueryScorer scorer = new QueryScorer(query);
Highlighter highlighter = new Highlighter(formatter, queryScorer);
//You can set a fragmenter as well, by default it will split into fragments 100 chars in size, using SimpleFragmenter.

String highlightedSnippet = highlighter.getBestFragment(myAnalyzer, fieldName, fieldContent);
```